# How to trigger a href click event from the parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

With below code I'm trying to click `a` tag click event from the parent `li` tag. But it gives me this error:

**Why I want to do this:**

When I click the **PHP PDO** link we need to cursor move in to that text not the `li` tag. I'm trying to fix it using this. But I know we can call that `href` from the `li` click event by getting the `a href` attribute and set it into the `window.location.href`. But still trying to trigger the `a href` click event when I click the `li` tag.

**HTML**

```
<li class="tags" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <a class="link_em" href="?l=1" id="1">List1</a>
</li>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('li.tags').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).children('a').click();
    return false;
});
```

**Error:**

I got this error when I use above code.

```
 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

**UI:**

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/k92dep45/

**Edited:**

> I done this ugly thing, but I am still looking proper solution:

```
$('li.tags a').on('click', function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
$('li.tags').on('click', function (e) {
  window.location.href = $(this).children('a.link_em').attr('href');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You might have recursive call of some function on your page. Is this the only jQuery code written on the page ?

Comment: By returning `false` you're stopping the `a` element's default behaviour (navigating to a different page) and the event propagates to the parent hence the `Maximum call stack....` error

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay no there's more jquery function in above page.

Comment: It sort of begs the question _why_ you'd want to do this.

Comment: I previously added `a` tag inside `li` tag with `href`. But now I want to trigger that `href` attribute when click the `li`

Comment: @Elshan have you ever considered to make the `<a>` fill up the `<li>` so no matter where you click on `<li>` you are clicking the `<a>` as well? Take a look at my answer Demo 3,

Answer (score 2):

You can use below version for the above code

```
$('li.tags').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
// Do your stuff.
e.preventDefault();
   window.location.href= thishref;
});
```

Here the second argument is the children 'a' in the click event of jQuery.

The problem is that you keep calling the same element which leads to the `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Look at the below example.

```
function foo(){
   foo();
}

foo();
```

In the above code, we are calling `foo()` again and again and it will also produce the same result.

Comment: unfortunately this not work for me.
`$('li.tags a').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                console.log($(this).text());
            });
            $('li.tags').on('click','a', function (e) {
                $(this).children('a').click();
            });`

Comment: @Elshan can you explain a bit more. Your code is different than what I have suggested.

Comment: I understood your explanation by the way, I've used your code but it's didn't call the `a href` event.  https://jsfiddle.net/elshan/nr6aas2c/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it differently by changing the `href` of the `window` to the `href` stored in your `a` tag, getted by using this instruction:

```
$(this).children('a').attr("href");
```

Try to implement, or run the following code snippet to confirm if its resolving your problem & get the expected render:

```js
$('li.tags').on('click', function (e) {
    window.location.href= $(this).children('a').attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="tags" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <a class="link_em" href="?l=1" id="1">List1</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `event.stopPropagation()` on `a` element and prevent event "bubbling" otherwise you create infinite loop and that is why you get that error.

```js
$('li.tags').on('click', function() {
  $(this).children('a').click();
});


$('li.tags a').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  e.preventDefault() // This is just for demo
  console.log($(this).text())
})
```

```css
a {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li {
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="tags" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <a class="link_em" href="?l=1" id="1">List1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Edit

After rereading the question, I think that OP has over complicated things (as have I obviously). Added a simpler version of Demo 1 labeled Demo 2. And added Demo 3 which is solution that uses no JavaScript/jQuery just CSS.

## Capture Phase

When you need fine grained control over the event chain `.addEventListener()` is better suited to handle particular aspects like firing the event on the capture phase instead of the bubbling phase. The reason why is because `li.tag` will be before `a.link` on the first phase (i.e. capture phase) of the event chain. We assign capture or bubbling phase by assigning the appropriate boolean value to the third parameter:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {...}, false);
```

This is default, which is set at `false` for the bubbling phase.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {...}, true);
```

This will make the registered object (e.g.`document` in this example) listen and act on the capture phase.
The following demo -- during capture phase -- will:

1. assign the clicked `li.tag` as the `event.target`...
2. ...then invoke `e.stopPropagation()` so the `a.link` nested within the `li.tag` will not be included in the event chain. The bubbling phase is skipped as well.
3. Instead, this `a.link` becomes `e.target` on a new event chain because the trigger method `.click()` is invoked on it.

---

### Test

The 3rd link of List0 tests whether `a.link` is indeed triggered by `.click()` or firing during capture or bubbling phase, or is the `event.target`. Because each `a.link` in List0 has `pointer-events:none` which makes `a.link` oblivious to any mouse or click event from a user, we can conclude:

1. that any activation of said `a.link` is entirely dependant upon its parent `li.tag` being clicked by a user.
2. during the capture phase, no click event will reach `a.link` due to `e.stopPropagation()` and `pointer-events:none` it can't be `e.target`.
3. bubbling phase isn't even there for `a.link` because of `e.stopPropagation()`
4. As that event chain dies off `.click()` is fired and `a.link` goes off like a second stage rocket

When clicking anywhere on the 3rd list item we get these results:

- log: `Target: LI`
- Does not jump to List2

When clicking the first or second list item of List0 we get these results:

- log: `LinkID: {0-1 or 0-2}`
- log: `Target: A`
- log: `Target: LI`
- Jumps to List1 or List2

---

### Errors

In the Fiddle, there were 2 instances of invalid HTML:

Error 1: `<ui>`

Correct: `<ul>`

Error 2: All `<a>` had the same id, all id must be unique

```
   <a class="link_em" href="?l=1" id="1">List1</a>

   <a class="link_em" href="?l=2" id="1">List2</a>
```

Correct:

```
   <a href='#l1-1' class='link' id='0-1'></a>

   <a href='#l1-2' class='link' id='0-2'></a>
```

You'll notice that the classes and ids in HTML are slightly different, but it'll be ok to change back to your own as long as you mind the errors mentioned above.

---

### Demo 1

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.className === 'tag') {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var link = e.target.querySelector('a');
    console.log('ID: ' + link.id);
    link.click();
    console.log('Target: ' + e.target.tagName);
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log('Target: ' + e.target.tagName);
    return false;
  }
}, true);
```

```css
ul {
  height: 90px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

li {
  height: 30px;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer
}

.link {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

b {
  float: left;
}

hr {
  margin-bottom: 1500px
}

.as-console {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 150px;
  color: blue;
}

.top {
  width: 100px;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Capture Phase Demo</h1>
<details>
  <summary>Test</summary>
  <p>Third list item is not a .tag.</p>
  <dl>
    <dt>Results:</dt>
    <dd>Logged: "Target: LI"(or "Target: "B")</dd>
    <dd>Did not log: "ID:0-2"</dd>
    <dd>Did not jump to List2</dd>

    <dt>Conclusion:</dt>
    <dd>Links on List0 do not respond to mouse or click events from user. Therefore in order to jump from List0 the link must be triggered programmatically.</dd>
  </dl>
</details>

<h2 id='l1-0'>List0</h2>
<ul>
  <li class='tag'>
    <a href='#l1-1' class='link' id='0-1'>List1</a>
  </li>
  <li class='tag'>
    <a href='#l1-2' class='link' id='0-2'>List2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='#l1-2' class='link' id='0-2'>Test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<b>1500px to List1 </b>
<hr>
<h2 id='l1-1'>List1</h2>
<ul>
  <li><a class='top' href='#l1-0'>Back to Top</a></li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<b>1500px to List2 </b>
<hr>
<h2 id='l1-2'>List2</h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class='top' href='#l1-0'>Back to Top</a>
  </li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

---

### Demo 2

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.className === 'tag') {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.target.querySelector('a').click();
  }
}, true);
```

```css
ul {
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid red
}

li {
  height: 100%;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='list0'>List0</h1>
<ul>
  <li class='tag'>
    <a href='#list1'>List1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<hr>
<h1 id='list1'>List1</h1>
<ul>
  <li class='tag'>
    <a href='#list0'>List0</a>
  </li>
```

### Demo 3

```css
ul {
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid blue
}

li {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0
}

a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='list0'>List0
  <h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href='#list1'>List1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <h1 id='list1'>List1
      <h1>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href='#list0'>List0</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```